# Ruby compute cumulative sum from endpoints recursively?

Tags: ruby, recursion

Given two numbers, say (14, 18), the problem is to find the sum of all the numbers in this range, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 recursively. Now, I have done this using loops but I have trouble doing this recursively.

Here is my recursive solution:

```
def sum_cumulative_recursive(a,b)

    total = 0

    #base case is a == b, the stopping condition
    if a - b == 0 
        puts "sum is: "
        return total + a 
    end

    if b - a == 0
        puts "sum is: "
        return total + b
    end

    #case 1: a > b, start from b, and increment recursively
    if a > b
        until b > a
            puts "case 1"
            total  = b + sum_cumulative_recursive(a, b+1)
            return total
        end
    end

    #case 2: a < b, start from a, and increment recursively
    if a < b
        until a > b
            puts "case 2"
            total = a + sum_cumulative_recursive(a+1, b)
            return total
        end 
    end
end
```

Here are some sample test cases:

```
puts first.sum_cumulative_recursive(4, 2)
puts first.sum_cumulative_recursive(14, 18)
puts first.sum_cumulative_recursive(-2,-2)
```

My solution works for cases where a > b, and a < b, but it doesn't work for a == b.

How can I fix this code so that it works?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It sounds like homework.  It smells like homework.  Is it homework, precioussss? Gollum, gollum.

Comment: what should be the result when `a==b`?

Comment: No, this was an interview question for an internship position.

Comment: return a+b + result(a+1,b) and include a case where if a==b return 0 then it will cascade down the initial call and you will have a result

Comment: Recursively? Aww, I was going to say `(14..18).reduce(:+)`. ;-)

Comment: Yep, this was an interview question, and so my constraint was recursive.

Comment: I suggest that, in future, you hold off awhile before selecting an answer, to encourage other, possibly better, solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sum_cumulative_recursive(a,b)
  return a if a == b
  a, b = [a,b].sort
  a + sum_cumulative_recursive(a + 1, b)
end
```

**EDIT**

Here is the most efficient solution I could see from some informal benchmarks:

```
def sum_cumulative_recursive(a,b)
  return a if a == b
  a, b = b, a if a > b
  a + sum_cumulative_recursive(a + 1, b)
end
```

Using:

```
Benchmark.measure { sum_cumulative_recursive(14,139) }
```

Benchmark for my initial response: 0.005733

Benchmark for @Ajedi32's response: 0.000371

Benchmark for my new response: 0.000115

I was also surprised to see that in some cases, the recursive solution approaches or exceeds the efficiency of the more natural `inject` solution:

```
Benchmark.measure { 10.times { (1000..5000).inject(:+) } }
# =>   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.027827)

Benchmark.measure { 10.times { sum_cumulative_recursive(1000,5000) } }
# =>   0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.019441)
```

Though you run into `stack level too deep` errors if you take it too far...

Comment: I don't understand the point of benchmarking methods that would never be used.  If one wanted the sum of the elements of a range, surely they would just calculate it directly, from the endpoints.

Comment: I'm not saying the benchmarks identify the best solution. I was mostly just curious to see how things played out with the asker's constraints (e.g., how costly instantiating an Array in my initial response would be). Of course under normal circumstances I would do `(14..18).inject(:+)` as @Ajedi32 notes above.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight, this was a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
def sum_cumulative_recursive(a, b)
  a, b = a.to_i, b.to_i # Only works with ints
  return sum_cumulative_recursive(b, a) if a > b
  return a if a == b
  return a + sum_cumulative_recursive(a+1, b)
end
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired result when `a > b`.

Comment: @kardeiz Could you clarify? What is the desired result when `a > b`?

Comment: According to the poster's code, it should basically flip the variables, so that you have a range of `min..max`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it.  I assume this is just an exercise, as the sum of the elements of a range `r` is of course just `(r.first+r.last)*(f.last-r.first+1)/2`.

```
def sum_range(range)
  return nil if range.last < range.first
  case range.size
  when 1 then range.first
  when 2 then range.first + range.last
  else
    range.first + range.last + sum_range(range.first+1..range.last-1)
  end
end

sum_range(14..18)  #=> 80
sum_range(14..14)  #=> 14
sum_range(14..140) #=> 9779
sum_range(14..139) #=> 9639
```

Comment: What? It doesn't even work: `undefined method 'size' for 14..18:Range`.

Comment: @Kardeiz, you have such a nice way with words.  It appears [Range#size](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-size) became available with v2.0. (I'm using v2.1).  For earlier versions I guess you'll have to use `range.last-range.first+1`.

Comment: @Cary, I meant no disrespect. Thanks for pointing out the version discrepancy.

Comment: @Cary, also, it would be nice if your answer used the question's method signature and addressed the min/max issue the other answers have dealt with.

Comment: @kardeiz, after posting my solution, I noticed I had used a range as the method argument, rather than the endpoints, but I concluded that difference was so trivial it didn't warrant an edit.  Also, I thought it might be useful for the asker to see how a range argument would be used.  Yes, I should have dealt with the range issue (see edit).  I didn't do so before because I assumed, incorrectly, that `(18..14)` (for example) would raise an exception.  (Curiously, `(18..14).size => 0)`.)  I now return `nil` in that case, but could have instead reversed the range.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have a front-end invocation that fixes out-of-order arguments, then a private recursive back-end which does the actual work. I find this is useful to avoid repeated checks of arguments once you've established they're clean.

```
def sum_cumulative_recursive(a, b)
  a, b = b, a if b < a
  _worker_bee_(a, b)
end

private
def _worker_bee_(a, b)
  a < b ? (a + _worker_bee_(a+1,b-1) + b) : a == b ? a : 0
end
```

This variant would cut the stack requirement in half by summing from both ends.

If you don't like that approach and/or you really want to trim the stack size:

```
def sum_cumulative_recursive(a, b)
  if a < b 
    mid = (a + b) / 2
    sum_cumulative_recursive(a, mid) + sum_cumulative_recursive(mid+1, b)
  elsif a == b
    a
  else
    sum_cumulative_recursive(b, a)
  end
end
```

This should keep the stack size to O(log |b-a|).